# Paypal refund API gives UnAuthorized Error

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

```
 const { paymentId } = req.body;

const refundURI = `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/${paymentId}/refund`;
// get access token
const { access_token } = await generateToken();
// console.log(JSON.stringify(access_token));

const refundObj = await Axios.post(refundURI, {
  headers: {
    Accept: `application/json`,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    amount: {
      currency_code: "USD",
      value: "10.00",
    },
  }),
});
```

I am trying to refund a paypal payment .I am generating access token but still its giving unAuthorized  with 401 status code .

Comment: Error is ::: name: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE',
      message: 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or 
a missing Authorization header.',

Comment: What is your access_token , clientId, debug_id of the response, and paymentId in this case? The error message is pretty clear that the problem is due to invalid credentials.

Comment: yes it was my mistake .I was passing body instead of headers to axios.